# Xperf and Tracelog showing always zero for pmc in windows

Tags: performance, hardware, xperf

I am trying to read hardware performance counters/PMC in windows 10.
I am using tracelog and xperf commandline to start the trace.
But pmc counter reading is always 0. (Running as Admin)

It was working fine but after restart the pmc count values is always 0. Do I need to activate some service to give access of pmc to xperf/tracelog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
I installed docker containers which require Hyper-V to be enabled.
Xperf and Tracelog cannot access PMC counters if the hypervisor is enabled.